# Kafka Error 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jackson, confluent-schema-registry

I need help with Kafka, use Ant project with Eclipse IDE, got error :

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not instantiate class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:396)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:401)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:436)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:421)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:394)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:392)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper.builder(JsonMapper.java:114)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.json.jackson.Jackson.newObjectMapper(Jackson.java:64)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.json.jackson.Jackson.newObjectMapper(Jackson.java:55)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaSerializer.<init>(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaSerializer.java:47)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer.<init>(KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer.java:41)
        ... 43 more
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
```

if jackson* libs removed it throws some like `NoClassDefFoundError...`  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonMerge` so i import missing jackson* . if i import the error as shown happen :

```
Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
```

[image: lib import]

another information i deploy in 2 place with same docker and same setting, 1 in my local mac, 2 in AWS server with Ubuntu

in my local all work, nothing error happen, but in AWS Server that error happen

**------EDITED------**

I have tried my project with Ivy dependencies management, imported 2 Kafka dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
<info
organisation=""
module="project"
status="integration">
</info>
<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
<dependency org="org.apache.kafka" name="kafka-clients" rev="3.3.1"/>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-json-schema-serializer -->
<dependency org="io.confluent" name="kafka-json-schema-serializer" rev="7.3.1"/>
</dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

import:

```
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;


Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", url);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("max.block.ms", 10000);
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer.class.getName());
props.put("schema.registry.url", schemaurl);
Producer<String, Payment> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, Payment>(props);
ProducerRecord<String, Payment> record = new ProducerRecord<String, Payment>(topic, uuid, message);

Future<RecordMetadata> resp = producer.send(record);
            
System.out.print(resp.get());

producer.close();
```

new error appear but the error lib i can import with no error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.getBindings()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeBindings;
```

this lib automatically downloaded from ivy :

[image: Ivy lib]
[image: Ivy lib]

and i don't know what lib conflict

Comment: Can you use Ivy to manage packages with your Ant project rather than what seems to be manually adding JAR files?

Comment: "but in AWS Server that error happen" - Then show us your AWS server's classpath, not your Mac

Comment: the classpath inside the war, same machine use same .war

Comment: `/Users` classpath is not "inside the WAR"

Comment: And are you required to use Ant? or WAR files? Why not Maven + Spring with executable JARs, or simply build a [Docker image with `spring-boot`](https://blog.codecentric.de/buildpacks-spring-boot)?

Comment: I also want it like that (use Maven and Spring) but this project was originally use Ant generate WAR to deploy all libs use manual .jar, it takes time to change it, 
I will try ivy

Comment: edited with ivy

Comment: For starters, you don't need `kafka_2.13`, so remove that. And you don't need any Confluent `ccs` versions of anything. But your error is coming from `jackson-databind`